# Algebraic Integer and its minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, normed-spaces, integers, minimal-polynomials

Given k is a nonzero algebraic integer, I am trying to show 1/k is algebraic as well iff  f(0) = 1 or -1 where f(t) is the minimal polynomial over the rationals. Think I can show (<=) by the fact that the constant term of its minimal polynomial gives 1, from where 1/k will be a root of some monic polynomial with the terms in the minimal polynomial reversed.. For (=>) : I am not sure, do we make use of the norm of 1/k?

Comment: Do you mean $1/k$ is an algebraic `integer`?

Comment: Yep algebraic integer

Comment: How about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas?

Comment: Hmm care to elaborate? I can't see how that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number $k$ is an algebraic integer if and only if its (monic) minimal polynomial over the rationals has integer coefficients.

Indeed, if $k$ is the root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients, it will be the root of one of its irreducible factors, which are monic and with integer coefficients as well (Gauss’ lemma).

The *reverse* of a degree $n$ polynomial with nonzero constant term $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$ is
$$
\hat{f}(x)=a_n+a_{n-1}x+\dots+a_0x^n=x^nf(1/x)
$$
It follows that $f$ is irreducible if and only if $\hat{f}$ is irreducible. (Prove it.)

Now, suppose $k$ is an algebraic integer with minimal polynomial $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n$. Then $1/k$ is a root of $\hat{f}(x)$, which is irreducible, so $\hat{f}(x)=cg(x)$, where $g(x)=b_0+b_1+\dots+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n$ is the (monic) minimal polynomial for $1/k$. (Why the degree has to be the same?)

Thus
$$
a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\dots+a_{n-1}x+1=
cb_0+cb_1x+\dots+cb_{n-1}x^{n-1}+cx^n
$$
In particular, $cb_0=1$ and $c=a_0$, so $a_0b_0=1$.

Suppose $1/k$ is an algebraic integer. Then…

> $b_0$ is an integer, so $a_0=\pm1$.

Conversely, if $a_0=1$ or $a_0=-1$, then either $\hat{f}(x)$ or $-\hat{f}(x)$…

> is a monic polynomial with integer coefficients having $1/k$ as root.

Comment: Very nice indeed, let me ask a tangential qns if you don't mind, that is, suppose now that some (complex number) c  is precisely a root of the 'reversed' polynomial ^f(x) as above except now the coefficients 'a' are themselves algebraic integers. Can we use the same argument to prove that c must also be an algebraic integer? Or is this a totally different case..

Comment: @Homaniac If you know that $c$ is an algebraic integer when it satisfies a monic polynomial with algebraic integer coefficients, then the proof is the same.

Comment: Thanks, liking your crisp explanations man, I'm having qns about rings too if you can help~

Comment: It just occurred to me though with respect to my quick qns in the above reply that: it is NOT given that this particular (reversed) polynomial is minimal but only that it is monic and has algebraic integers as coefficients, ie it is not necessarily irreducible. So to prove the root c is an algebraic integer, it seems another method is needed..hm..I am thinking, by making use of the result of the OP, we can try to show 1/c has a minimal polynomial that satisfy f(0) =1 or -1 then we can conclude c is an algebraic integer as desired but I'm not sure how that can be shown precisely, any ideas? :/

Answer (score 0):

Let $k$ be an algebraic integer and consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(k)$. It is a well-known fact that the (field-theoretic) minimal polynomial of $k$ is the same as the (linear algebra) minimal polynomial of the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $\varphi: \mathbb{Q}(k) \to \mathbb{Q}(k)$ $x \mapsto kx$.

Note that if we use the standard basis $B = (1,k,k^2, \dots k^{n-1})$, where $n = [\mathbb{Q}(k):\mathbb{Q}]$, then the matrix of $\varphi$ has integral coefficients. To be precise, if the minimal polynomial of $k$ is $T^n+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$, we have $\operatorname{Mat}_B^B(\varphi)= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -a_0 \\
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -a_1 \\
0 & 1 & \ddots & \vdots & -a_2 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & \vdots \\
0 & \dots & 0 & 1 & -a_{n-1} \\
\end{pmatrix}$.

Suppose that $\frac{1}{k}$ is also an algebraic integer, say with minimal polynomial $T^n+b_{n-1}T^{n-1}+\dots+b_0$, then we have $k^{-n}+b_{n-1}k^{-n+1}+\dots+b_0=0$ Multiplying through by $k^{n-1}$, we see that $\frac{1}{k}=-b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}k-\dots-b_0k^{n-1}$, so if we consider the function $\psi: \mathbb{Q}(k) \to \mathbb{Q}(k)$ $x \mapsto \frac{x}{k}$, we have
$\operatorname{Mat}_B^B(\psi)=\begin{pmatrix}
-b_{n-1} & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
-b_{n-2} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-b_{n-2} & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots   & 0 & \dots &0 & 1 \\
-b_0     & 0 &  \dots &0 &0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ which again has integral coefficients. But the functions $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are inverses of each other. This means that $\operatorname{Mat}_B^B(\varphi) \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$, but this implies that the determinant of $\varphi$, which is just $a_0$, must be a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$. Note that conversely, if $a_0$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$, $\operatorname{Mat}_B^B(\varphi) \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$, and by Cayley-Hamilton the characteristic polynomial of the inverse matrix is a monic integral polynomial with root $\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: I was looking for a direct approach not involving matrices but glad to see another helpful perspective!